# Modify Bower config from CLI

Tags: node.js, certificate, npm, ssl-certificate, bower

I'm attempting to create a setup script for a server that will install npm/node and bower, as well as downloading all necessary bower packages.

However, I have a self-signed certificate authority. For npm, this is not an issue as I can run

```
npm config set cafile /etc/ssl/certs/custom.pem
```

But I don't see a similar option for bower. I understand creating a .bowerrc file is typically the way to configure bower options, but I need this to be a global config setting.

Is there any similar command to npm for bower? By which I mean the ability to set the global certificate authority?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Tyler